# Can I use tabindex on headlines and important text?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am testing my website with the **[screenreader plugin for chrome]**[1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) and with **MacOS built in voiceover utility**. As I tab from one interact-able element to another, the screenreader reads the label or aria-label. However, without putting `tabindex="0"` on headlines and other important items such as product name, product description, pricing information, disclaimers, instructions, etc., the focus never goes to those items and the screenreader never announces them.

**I want to put `tabindex="0"` on headlines and important text, but I've read that I should only put `tabindex` on interact-able items.**

Am I simply not using the screenreader correctly? What am I missing here? I want the user to be able to get an overview of all the important information on the page. It is not enough for the user to just jump between inputs and buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply unfamiliarity with a screen reader as you said.

You don't want to add `tabindex="0"` to everything as this would then make keyboard navigation for those not using assistive tech difficult (too many focus stops).

Additionally anything that receives focus should be interactive / clickable as you have already read about so it would confuse AT users too!

[this guide will help in learning how to use NVDA screen reader](https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/nvda-keyboard-shortcuts), there are similar guides for JAWS and Orca too.

There are two basic ways most people navigate to start off with. Up and down arrows to get to the next item and previous item, and number keys 1-6 to jump between headings (h1-h6 respectively) are enough to get around most well designed web pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the screenreader plugin for Chrome that I linked to and the macOS voiceover utility. Those don't seem to work with arrow keys or number keys. They only operate via tab/focus as far as I can tell. Thanks.

Comment: @mags, that would be a failure of the plugin.  **All** screen readers must have a way to navigate to all DOM elements.  That's typically with the up/down arrow keys (plus lots of other shortcut keys such as 'B' for next button, 'T' for next table, 'H' for next heading, etc).

Comment: @mags https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7031755#zippy=%2Cmove-through-a-page-with-keyboard-shortcuts it appears it is the same but you press search or launcher button and arrow keys to access the next item.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I'm afraid your first sentence and "it doesn't take long to learn" could be taken as an insult. I'm sure you didn't mean it that way, but you could delete these parts without changing the answer.

Comment: @mags I'd like to add that IF information is very important to filling out a form input, you actually might want them to get announced when focusing the input by means of tabs There are other elements like `fieldset`+`legend` and finally the `aria-describedby` attribute that can help with that.

Comment: @Andy , thank you for that hint.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: I still can't make that work for MacOS. If you have any info on what the "search" key would be for MacOS in that case please let me know.

Comment: @mags it will be whatever you have set as your "VoiceOver" key plus the arrow keys. I am not sure what the default is as I have changed mine to be TAB. If you search for "VoiceOver keyboard controls cheat sheet" in Google I would imagine they will detail that in one of the first results.

Comment: @andy I have changed it but I don't think that would have been a problem, "it doesn't take long" is not a specific length of time and is relative to a persons rate of learning, plus I did not say it was easy which is where most problems come from.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie It does come off a bit abrasive, but I've been at this too long to take offense honestly (jaded!)

Comment: Fair enough, I was just mirroring your words in your question so I thought it was acceptable, but I can take that on board, certainly wasn't meant to imply anything so my apologies there!